# OData dynamic properties - not part of $metadata?

Tags: odata

From reading [Open Types in OData v4 with ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/use-open-types-in-odata-v4), my understanding is that a $metadata call would not return dynamic properties as part of an entity's schema.

Since $select does not allow for a property's type to be specified, does that mean that an open entity's schema should be stored in the service somehow? Why shouldn't the dynamic properties be included in $metadata, then?

Comment: Nobody cares about the OData standard, *sigh*.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, dynamic properties aren't added to the metadata as they are typically there to cover the case of adding properties that either aren't there for all objects or adding properties that aren't known when building the metadata (otherwise, you could just use a normal property)

You can use this header to get more information about the types of properties in the the actual call, however, it doesn't supply the information for simple types like strings, ints etc which I found made this information quite difficult to use (but it is better than nothing!)

```
Accept: application/json;odata.metadata=full
```

For example, using the OData TripPin example service, calling this url: http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinServiceRW/People with that header will give you a new property in the payload `"AddressInfo@odata.type": "#Collection(Microsoft.OData.SampleService.Models.TripPin.Location)"`, which you can then use to understand the `AddressInfo` property

Comment: The contradictory part of this is that you can query and select (simple) dynamic properties, so that says to me that they must be part of the schema somehow.

Comment: It is possible to manually inspect your OData model object, it might be worth debugging and looking in there to help convince yourself that these dynamic properties aren't in there?

Comment: I'm asking this question from the point of view of the implementer of the service. One idea is to simply store everything as a string, and assume string type in $select. In this light, the use of cast() in $filter also makes sense, but from the implementation's perspective, this means rather inefficient storage/queries.